# Splitting mysql query output into variables

Tags: mysql, shell, mariadb

I'm trying using shell script, to split mysql query output and save it in variables. My code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -ra tokens<<<$(mysql -u root -p'password' -D'users_info' -se 'SELECT token FROM users_logs')
for i in "${tokens[@]}"; do
        echo $i
done
var=$(mysql -u root -p'password' -D'users_info' -se 'SELECT token FROM users_logs')
echo $var
```

and script output:

```
2z7bhxbk7egquokj855d3
2z7bhxbk7egquokj855d3 we3cq1d95drdq3micu9cn we3cq1d95drdq3micu9cn
```

As you can see, query result is the bottom one and it contains 3 tokens, but when I'm trying to split, it returns only first one. I think that, it's delimiter fault, but I don't really know what delimiter is used here, if not space.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: mysql output is tab delimited. look up man bash and make your "read" recognizes this

Comment: @danblack with `IFS='   ';` before read, there is no change in first output, but second echo is splitted into rows. Is there another way to make "read" recognizes delimiter?

Comment: `read -d \t  ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` should have no trouble with tabs. I suspect the issue is really the newlines - one line, one read. Try it this way -

```
while read -r t; do
  tokens+=("$t")
  echo "${tokens[@]" # should show them accumulating
done < <(mysql -u root -p'password' -D'users_info' -se 'SELECT token FROM users_logs')
```

e.g.,

```
$: while read -r t; do tokens+=("$t"); echo "${tokens[@]}"; done < <( printf "%s\n" a b c  )
a
a b
a b c
```

Whereas, what you are doing is basically this:

```
$: read -ra t < <( printf "%s\n" a b c d e f g ) # only reads 1st line
$: echo "${#t[@]} ${t[@]}"
1 a
```

*In this specific case...*

You *could* probably use an otherwise bad-habit direct assignment to an array.

```
tokens=( $(mysql -u root -p'password' -D'users_info' -se 'SELECT token FROM users_logs') )
```

But don't, unless you are going to add some data checking in your query. This is generally a horrible habit for several reasons, even if those tokens *shouldn't* have any embedded whitespace.

The way you are doing it is better. You just need a read per line.

Comment: Thanks for answer, my code works with @danblack advice, I added `read -d \t`, but I'll check it your way also. Thanks